# ASP.NET - Discarding Changes on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, button, history

I have a repeater consisting of several textboxes and four buttons.  The four buttons are:

i) Edit
ii) Delete
iii) Save Changes
iv) Cancel

The first two buttons are displayed on page load whilst the latter two are hidden.

Upon clicking the edit button, the textboxes (which had been previously disabled) are enabled and the former two buttons are hidden whilst the latter two are shown.

Up to there, everything works fine.  The problem is that if the user changes the contents of one of the textboxes and clicks "Cancel" instead of "Save Changes", the contents remain with the changes.

Luckily, the changes are not saved in the database so it is more of a visual thing but it is annoying.  In such a situation, I want the content to go back as it was before the user made the changes and clicked the 'Cancel' button.

How can I do this please?

I tried making use of history.go(0) but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the cancel button:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="ButtonCancel" onclick="history.go(0)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either re-query the database or use client side scripting to save the state before any changes and then restore the old textboxes values when the button is pressed.

Comment: I would actually like to do the latter so that there are no postbacks.  Should I store the initial value in a variable and then re-assign it to the control on "Cancel" button click?

Comment: Yes. On click event of Edit you can store the initial state of the textboxes in some variables and on click event of Cancel you will restore the values from the variables to the textboxes.

Comment: Hi there :)  I have saved the control in a variable called TextBoxDescription.

Now, I am trying to change the content of the description textbox on 'cancel' button click.  I have the following piece of code in jquery:

$('.Desc').val(TextBoxDescription)

However, when I click cancel, the contents appear as [object].  The problem lies with TextBoxDescription.  I have to use a method which gets the text in the control.  Do you know how this can be done in jQuery please?

Comment: Ok, I used the val method after TextBoxDescription and it now works.  However, the problem is that all of the textboxes in the other repeaters have this value.  How can I solve this problem?  This is the code:

$('.Desc').val(TextBoxDescription.val())

Comment: .Desc selects all the elements which have class="Desc". That is why all the textboxes of this class are affected. You should use a different selector or to add all the elements of a specific repeater on a unique class or give each element a unique Id e.g class="Desc Rep1" id="Rep1Desc".

Answer (score 1):

Save the old values on the edit click event. On the cancel event put the old values back in.

Answer (score 0):

When the user click on the edit button you can save the content of the textboxes in hidden fields.
and when he clicks on the cancel button take the previous values from the hidden fields to the textboxes.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     function edit_onclick() {
         form1.hisotry.value = form1.Text1.value;
     }

     function cancel_onclick() {
         form1.Text1.value = form1.hisotry.value;
     }


</script>
```